# Connection Reset error in HttpClient

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-reset

This is scenario I am testing. The steps are as follows

1. Create an instance of HttpClient(org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient)3.1
2. Use the instance to get response from a url (http://www.example.com/submitData)
3. Bring down the server hosting the url mentioned in step 2.
4. Bring up the url
5. Wait till the url is up
6. Use the instance of HttpClient created in step 1 to get response from the url (http://www.example.com/getData)

I get an error - Connection Reset.
Can anyone help me understand.

I have used the following params in the HttpClient

```
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(0));
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", new Boolean(true));
```

Edited after comments from Peter
This is how I create the HttpClient

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope("www.example.com", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM);
Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "pwd");
httpClient.getState().setCredentials(authScope, defaultcreds);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(0));
httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", new Boolean(true));
```

To establish connection, I use the following

```
GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod("http://"+httpClient.getHostConfiguration().getHost()+"/getData");
int statusCode = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
```

I want the httpclient instance to preserve the hostname and port and credentials.

This is exact execption message that I get -  "Connection reset".

More info - I am executing the test from eclipse. If I run the test case in debug mode, I dont get this exception.

Answer (score 2):

I think the behaviour is reasonable because when the server goes down the client socket on the server goes away too. The client still holds old socket but this socket is gone on the server. You should reconnect from client.

AFAIK the `stale` parameter allows the client to close the connection the clean way (without Exception) but not prevent from disconnection.

Comment: But I am not looking to persist any connection with the url. The calls made by HttpClient are REST calls and all I want is the HttpClient object to preserve data like host and port.

Comment: So show us how do you instantiate HttpClient and opens the connection.

Comment: I have modified the question to reflect the steps involved in creating the instance of HttpClient

Comment: Can you post the exact Exception message.

Comment: @PeterMnn I have edited the question to add more info. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This looks suspicious

httpClient.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", new Integer(0));

Having a timeout set to 0ms would likely terminate the request prematurely?